# Event startdate and alarmtime from datepicker

Tags: ios, xcode, uidatepicker

I will add an event to the calendar.

My code is correct but I need the date and the time from Datepicker.

How to set date and time from the datepicker for the following code:

```
EKEventStore *es = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[es requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    /* This code will run when uses has made his/her choice */
    EKEvent *myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:es];
    myEvent.title = @"New Event";

    myEvent.startDate = [NSDate date]; // I need to set date from Datepicker

    NSTimeInterval interval = 60*+5; // I need to set time from Datepicker
    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:interval];
    [myEvent addAlarm:alarm];
    myEvent.endDate = [[NSDate date] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:myEvent.startDate];

    [myEvent setCalendar:[es defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;
    [es saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
}];
```

You can see the comment where I will set the date and time.

Thanks.

Comment: what you want in interval what is 68*+5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions for date and time. And I am sharing the code with you:

For date from datepicker:

```
NSDate *selectedDate = self.datePicker.date;
myEvent.startDate = selectedDate;
```

For alarm time from datepicker:

```
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:selectedDate];
[myEvent addAlarm:alarm];
```

That's all.

Good Coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use (Assuming `datePicker` as your outlet for [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) ):

```
NSDate *date = self.datePicker.date; 
myEvent.startDate = date;
```

Or in one line :

```
myEvent.startDate = self.datePicker.date
```

For time interval:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = <time in seconds>;
```

EDIT: (After your comment)

As you need only time, not date+time. Then you need to use `NSDateFormatter` and format the date.

Comment: This code is not running because my datepicker initialize with date and time..

Not only date

Comment: I need to both date and time from datepicker.

Comment: @juniorCoder: Tell finally what you want? date or date+time, you talking differently.

Comment: I told it in the question, I need both from datepicker.

Comment: @juniorCoder: date contains both date and time with timezone. I am not understanding what you need?

Comment: I need that: User will choose date and time from datepicker.

And I will set them to my event for startdate and for alarmtime

Comment: @juniorCoder: If you save myEvent.startDate=self.datePicker.date then it will save the time also.

Comment: I used the following code for date:
NSDate *selectedDate = self.datePicker.date;
        myEvent.startDate = selectedDate;

But it didn't work

Comment: It didn't work means that I didn't add an event to the calendar.

Comment: I added now ok. But could you tell me how to set time for alarm from datepicker?

Comment: You need to set a future date with time. And Make a timer that will poll every second to check if this the time to start the alarm. If you have selected a time has is invalid(already passed) throw a warning static that.

Comment: No, I will just add an alarm with using this code EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:interval];
    [myEvent addAlarm:alarm];

But I need to time from datepicker, that's all.

Comment: I dont have mac with me now. i can check only tomorw from office. if you can send me your code. till then try.

Comment: And one easy way to check, **try by hard coded time**, if it is working good or not.